# symfony and DQL

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

i have :

```
public function findTodasLasCompras($usuario_id)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $dql = 'SELECT v, o, t
            FROM OfertaBundle:Venta v
            JOIN v.oferta o
            JOIN o.tienda t
            WHERE v.usuario = :id
            ORDER BY v.fecha DESC';

    $consulta = $em->createQuery($dql);
    $consulta->setParameter('id', $usuario_id);
    $result = $consulta->getResult();
    return $consulta->getResult();
}
```

and when i execute it fails with it's error:

ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: Cupon\OfertaBundle\Entity\Oferta in C:\wamp\www\sympony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php line 477

in C:\wamp\www\sympony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php line 477
at ErrorHandler->handle('8', 'Undefined index: Cupon\OfertaBundle\Entity\Oferta',

help! please! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to tranform your 'JOIN' to 'LEFT JOIN'.

If an usario exists well with id 8, maybe he is not linked to oferta or tienda, so the jointure return nothing, but left join keep usario instance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, replace this:

```
$result = $consulta->getResult();
return $consulta->getResult();
```

with this:

```
$result = $consulta->getResult();
return $result;
```

Maybe you should reinstall Symphony, it seems something is broken.